# Git clone button

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, git

I need to create a button that will execute git clone for the client`s desktop (with git-cli or TortoiseGit).
Is it even possible? 
How can I do that?

Comment: Is it impossible from client side ?

Comment: I expect this can *only* be done client-side for security reasons. Imagine the vulnerabilities possible if a server could just push files to your computer.